# In Bash, why would 'echo ?' print 1?

Tags: bash, glob

I noticed that when I try to echo ?, it prints 1.

I read that it is a "wild card (single character). [question mark] The ? character serves as a single-character "wild card" for filename expansion in globbing, as well as representing one character in an extended regular expression." (as written in a documents titled "Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: A complete guide to shell scripting, using Bash" that I read on the web).

```
$ echo ?
1

$ echo ? ? ?
1 1 1

$ echo ? 1 ?
1 1 1

$ ls shai?n
shai.txt

bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: It works for me (I get the question mark, not the number 1), I am using `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Thought I answered a similar problem before (missed it searching by title), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631316/bash-shell-for-loop-returns-different-values/20631682#20631682

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `?` expands to all one character files or itself if none exists
- `*` expands to all files or itself if none eixsts

So only way this can happen is if you have a single-character file called `1` in your working directory. e.g.

```
> mkdir emptydir && cd emptydir 
> echo ?
?
> touch 1 && echo ?
1
```

Also note as comments point out you can print it by doing `echo "?"` or `echo \?`

Comment: Probably worth mention how the OP would *actually* output a `?`. (Though to be fair, they didn't ask.)

Comment: with escaping(\\) or quoting.

Comment: Yep, I had a file named 1 in the directory where I tested this :) I appreciate your taking the time to answer this question!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a file called '1' in the current working directory.

```
# echo ?
?

# touch 1
# echo ?
1
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash's [`nullglob` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion), you can suppress printing the glob pattern as a string:

```
$ echo ?
?
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo ?

$ touch A
$ echo ?
A
```